# Disable closed stage in opportunity guided path Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Is it possible to disable closed stage in opportunity guided path
[image: see image here]

We have some requirement where we need to disable this closed stage and we want to add a button where we can launch our LWC component instead of standard component which is being launched by system. We want to override that dependency popup

Thanks in Advance